# Relative factorisation with scalar quantities

Tags: polynomials, factorization, data-types

I'd like to find a natural way to tell mathematica that a given unknown in a polynomial should be treated as a number, unlike the other variables.

Typically I'd like to sum two polynomials in several variables, say

```
P[x,y,z]=x y^2 z + 2x y z^2 + x^2 y^2
Q[x,y,z]=x^2 y z - x y z^2 + x^2 z^2
```

with a scaling factor `a` on one of them, such that the output of `P + a Q` looks like;

```
x y^2 z + (2-a) x y z^2 + x^2 y^2 + a x^2 y z + a x^2 z^2
```

So mathematica should really interpret `a` as a number.

Comment: This site relies on an economy of upvotes. Yet, you felt that the accepted answer was worth the checkmark, but not an upvote. Doesn't that strike you as strange?

Comment: @ rcollyer; I guess I can't upvote before having 15 rep, so I did as best as I could to acknowledge that the answer was useful to me.

Comment: Weird. I was under the impression that you could upvote answers to your own question. My apologies, and a +1 because I liked the question.

Comment: No worries ! (also thanks for allowing me to upvote on mathematica.SE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MonomialList` may provide functionality you're looking for here.

```
P[x,y,z]=x y^2 z + 2x y z^2 + x^2 y^2;
Q[x,y,z]=x^2 y z - x y z^2 + x^2 z^2;
P[x,y,z]+a Q[x,y,z]//Expand
```

will yield

```
x^2 y^2 + a x^2 y z + x y^2 z + a x^2 z^2 + 2 x y z^2 - a x y z^2
```

Now, to get the factorization you're looking for,

```
MonomialList[x^2 y^2 + a x^2 y z + x y^2 z + a x^2 z^2 + 2 x y z^2 - a x y z^2, {x, y, z}]
Plus@@%
```

gives

```
{x^2 y^2, a x^2 y z, a x^2 z^2, x y^2 z, (2 - a) x y z^2}
x^2 y^2 + a x^2 y z + x y^2 z + a x^2 z^2 + (2 - a) x y z^2
```

**Edit:**
I should also add that using `Expand` in this progression of steps is redundant if you're going to roll it up into one line, as `MonomialList` handles that functionality as well. I only used it here so you could see the polynomial in the form similar to your description. To generalize it as a function you'd do something like

```
Clear[FactorConstants]
FactorConstants[p_,vars_List]:=Plus@@MonomialList[p,vars]
```

Usage:

```
FactorConstants[P[x,y,z]+a Q[x,y,z],{x,y,z}]

x^2 y^2 + a x^2 y z + x y^2 z + a x^2 z^2 + (2 - a) x y z^2
```